# How to delete/update async way and when should I unsubscribe?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm currently a newbie with Angular.

One of the main goal of async pipe is automatically take care of subscribing and unsubscribing for you.

**1.**
When dealing with delete or update (both are API services), Should I need to unsubscribe via ngOnDestroy?

```
projects$: Observable<Project[]>;

constructor(
    private projectService: ProjectService,
) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.loadProject();
}   


loadProject(){
    this.projects$ = this.projectService.getProjects()
    .pipe(
        map(result => {
            if(result.success){
                return result.data;
            }
        })
    );
}


deleteProject(){
    if(this.projectToDelete){
        const id = this.projectToDelete.id;
        this.projectService.deleteProject(id).subscribe(result => {
            if(result.success){
                this.loadProject();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

2. Is there another way to delete a specific element from Observable without calling again the api that refreshs the `projects$`? Something like this, instead with the one above:

   ```
   //In this case this.projects type is not an Observable.
   deleteProject(){
       if(this.projectToDelete){
           const id = this.projectToDelete.id;
           this.projectService.deleteProject(id)
           .subscribe(result => {
               if(result.success){
                   this.projects = this.projects.filter(item => {
                       return item.id != id;
                   });
                   this.projectToDelete = null;
                   this.closeModal();
               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

it really depends on your requirement but you can always either use the `async` pipe which will handle the lifecycle of an observable for you by `subscribing` and `unsubscribing`

-You can use some of the RxJS operators that will handle the `unsubscribe` for you. Like `take(1)`, `first()`, `of()`, `from()`.

-Unsubscribe on the NgDestroy as you mention

Also, destroying is not a thing for Observable, you either `unsubscribe`, `complete` or **both**.

FYI in reactive programming is better to do the Declarative approach

wait, what is that?

```
testObject$ = this.http.get(url).pipe(
      map((resp: any) => 
           ({
            id: resp.data.id,
            view: resp.data.view,
            resourceName: resp.data.resourcename,
            loadCapacity: resp.data.loadcapacity
          }) as TestObject)
      );

  }
```

You see what I did? I erased the method.

then in your component you call it `testService.testObject$`

You see what I did I got rid of the method and here's why:

1. -Leverage the power of rxjs observables and opeartors
2. -effectively compatible streams
3. -easy share observables
4. -readily react to user action